# How get data from Angular to Core JSP?

Tags: java, angular, jsp, servlets

I got null value in JSP when I try to send data from angular service 
    export class AllService {

```
  url: any;
   cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.cpHeaders });

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  register(data){
    console.log(data);
    return 
this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/client_api/register.jsp',data)
    .pipe(map((res: Response)=>{ return res.json()}));
  }
```

This is my angular service, I have to read data in jsp page

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<%
    String name=request.getParameter("name");  
    String email=request.getParameter("email"); 
    String mobile=request.getParameter("mobile"); 
    String password=request.getParameter("password"); 
    String address=request.getParameter("address"); 
    out.println(name);
    out.println(email);
    out.println(mobile);
    out.println(password);
    out.println(address);
%>
```

It returns null value

Comment: You have you printed the data before sending it to JSP, Does it has all the values or the value you are expecting?

Comment: why on earth a JSP? This is way easier with say Resteasy or the like. Have you checked parameters passed to JSP?

Comment: why are you using the servlet tag if you are not using any servlets?

Comment: i check values before pass to jsp i got expected values in request header as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your Angular code sends your `data` as a JSON object within the request body, but your JSP code expects url-encoded body content.

You can change request body format by turning second argument of `_http.post` into `HttpParams` instance and setting correct request header like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

...

this._http.post(
  '/client_api/register.jsp',
  new HttpParams({ fromObject: data }),
  {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
).pipe(map((res: Response)=>{ return res.json()}));
```